# What is a word that means a very important personal truth?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word for a personal belief that is revered for its intrinsic, universal truth, and moral nature/aspects. Below are words I have considered, along with their definition from Merriam-Webster. I have added, in italics, what the word seems to be lacking in connotation. Any input is greatly appreciated, as I have been searching for the right word/phrase for quite some time. I've also included an example sentence, too.

---

Examples:

> She (holds in high regard) the type of compassionate care that a nurse provides, seeing it as irreplaceable, and, as such, their inclusion on interdisciplinary teams for mental health care is paramount.

or

> Her (conviction) that nurses provide an unmatched, compassionate form of care, is the basis for her (belief, maxim) of the necessity of including RNs in any interdisciplinary team.

---

Words I've ruled out:

- **Conviction**: strong belief or persuasion--*seems to lack the sense morality, not emphatic enough*
  [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conviction)
- **Maxim**: general truth, fundamental principle, or rule of conduct--*lacks the personal aspect*
  [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maxim)
- **Value**: something intrinsically valuable or desirable--*too generic, not emphatic enough*
  [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/value)
- **Manifesto**: written statement describing policies, goals, procedures--*obviously, here the issue is that this word refers to a written statement, however, it has the elements of personal, moral and of penultimate importance*
  [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/manifesto)

Comment: Your first example wants a verb and your second examples wants nouns. Which are you looking for?

Comment: Either one, at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Credo

> a guiding belief or principle

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/credo

> a set of beliefs that influences the way you live

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/credo

> A credo is a set of beliefs, principles, or opinions that strongly influence the way a person lives or works.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/credo